# A Boundary Value Problem $y^{''} + xy = 0, x \in [a, b]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following problem is an exam problem, which I could not do. But I attempted it as far as I can do.

Let $y$ be a nontrivial solution of the boundary value problem $$y^{''} + xy = 0, x \in [a, b],   y(a) = y(b) = 0.$$

Then

1. $b > 0$
2. $y$ is monotonic in $(a, 0)$ if $a < 0 < b.$
3. $y^{'}(a) = 0.$
4. $y$ has infinitely many zeros in $[a, b].$

It is a Sturm Liouville Problem. If $y$ is a nontrivial solution to the problem, then $y$ is an eigen function corresponding to the eigen value 0.

Then we know that the eigen values of a Sturm Liouville Problem can be arranged in an strictly increasing sequence $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2 < ... < \lambda_n < ... $ which tends to infinity.

Also we know that corresponding to each eigen value  $\lambda_n $, the eigen function $y_n(x)$ has exactly $n - 1$ roots in $(a, b).$ Then the option 4 is False. But I do not know what the $n$ is ?

I do not have any idea about other options. I could not even solve the $y^{''} + xy = 0$. Can it be done by Power series method?

Comment: i think $y''+xy=0$ is called the airy differential equation which defines the airy functions $ai(x), bi(x).$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function

Comment: Yeah, thanx @abel. But how to solve it? What is the methodology? How to use the boundary conditions then?

Comment: @ParveenChhikara , try a solution of form $\sum a_n x^n$ maybe , and find coefficients.

Comment: Same question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/819550/let-y-be-a-nontrivial-solution-of-the-boundary-value-problem-fracd2ydx2